# Waiting for mongodb to prealloc

Tags: mongodb, automation

Does MongoDB create a file I can poll for in order to determine when prealloc is done? Right now I have a script to run `rs.init(..config..)`, but I need to wait with triggering it until mongod is up and running.

Since `tail -f | grep .. | xarg..` the log file is a bit of a flaky hack, I wondered if there is any other way to determine that mongod is done with prealloc?

Answer (score 1):

We have the same problem for testing replica sets with the PHP driver. Here we use the mongo shell's `ReplSetTest()` functionality to get around this. You can see here how that works:
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/blob/master/tests/utils/myconfig.js#L9

However, I am not sure how well this works for non-test environments as the amount of options you can give are rather limited (such as, you can't set a data dir properly as things are [hardcoded](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/shell/replsettest.js#L522)). All the functions and code for this is all in JavaScript at https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/shell/replsettest.js — this should give you an overview how it works and allows you to rewrite it in your preferred language.

Answer (score 0):

try to use inotify (i am not sure exactly), for example, if it is necessary to determine that the file is closed after writing:

[maverick@mutabor ~]$ pyinotify -e IN_CLOSE_WRITE /tmp/testfile

Comment: i agree ;), i am wrote what not sure exactly